# what does it mean to only allow expected input in php?

Tags: php, validation, gpc

I'm reading a book on php security, and on input validation chapter there's a small section that talks about only allowing expected input.

This is the code that they show:

```
<?php
$expected = array( 'carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle' );
foreach( $expected AS $key ) {
if ( !empty( $_POST[ $key ] ) ) {
${$key} = $_POST[ $key ];
}
else {
${$key} = NULL;
}
}
?>
```

I'm kind of confused, there's a small paragraph that explains what the code does. For what I get it assigns a value from the array as a key to $_POST. It also says that the array should be done programatically copied out of the GPC array.

What I don't understand is in what cases should I use this? And what is the GPC array?

Comment: IMHO, you should toss this book in the trash. Was it written in 1999? The above code doesn't destroy the $_POST array, so you could accidentally use it later without thinking; and it dumps all the variables into whatever namespace this code is put in. A better way would be to go over the $_POST array and nullify values not in the list. And even better it would put those values into a new post array/object and destroy the original.

Comment: @DampeS8N oh really? I didnt know! Do you by any chance know a more updated book? or maybe a link where I can learn about the subject. Thanks for your comment, the book is from a couple years ago but I didn't know it would point to the wrong way.

Comment: This website is a good place to start. Some of the links in the answers are good too. Generally, I would suggest not learning from a book. But I understand that some people learn better from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates variables from data in the `$_POST` array. The names of the variables are taken from the keys of the `$_POST` array. PHP calls this (i.e. naming variables dynamically) [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

This is usually a bad idea, because you do not control, which keys are present in the `$_POST` array, and thus, which variables are created. The user of your website controls this. A malicious user might name the POST variables in such a way that they overwrite variables that you intended for different purposes.

The book suggests to allow keys in the `$_POST` array to overwrite variables *in a controlled manner*. That's what `$expected = array('carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle')` is for. This and the following code only creates the variables `$carModel`, `$year` and `$bodyStyle`. If, for example, a user posts `current_user_has_admin_rights=1` to you application, a variable `$current_user_has_admin_rights` with a value of 1 will *not* be created.

My suggestion is to to stay away from variable variables alltogether and instead access the POST values through the `$_POST` array only. This makes it clear where the value comes from, an thus makes it easier to spot if such a value is handled in an unsecure manner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I understand better now. I'll take a look at variable variables as I didnt know of them, but I'll follow your suggestion also.

Answer (score 1):

GPC = Get Post Cookie, it's referring to variables coming from the user/browser. So instead of using $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE you should be cleaning and validating that data into a variable(s) that you can trust and know is clean.

As for the suggestion, what they are doing is limiting what your code has access to. In the above code example, you would probably have a form on the page with elements named carMOdel, year, and bodyStyle. What the code here is doing is restricting your code to ONLY interact with those 3 elements.

This prevents someone from passing extra parameters to your page in an attempt to inject code or some sort of SQL injection attack or any other number of things. In a simple example like this it might not make sense. But there are cases where people are taking form/api requests and running loops over everything in one of GPC arrays and doing stuff with anything in there. I would suggest not doing that to begin with.

This is just 1 of MANY things to protect your server/database. When developing webapps you should take the stance of trusting NOTHING that comes from the user side.

As far as security goes, OWASP is a great source for learning. [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet) is a little cheat sheet that is in the works for php.

Comment: Thanks Nathan Hess for your explanation! +1 for the link :)

Answer (score 0):

**It also says that the array should be done programatically copied out of the GPC array.**

This could mean that you shouldn't necessarily write:

```
$expected = array('carModel', 'year', 'bodyStyle');
```

Rather write something like:

```
$expected = getExpectedInput('carForm');
```

Where the function getExpectInput would query the database for the input that should be in the form 'carForm'. Or perhaps it could be in a file and this function would fetch that content. They basically mean, it's not a good idea to hard-code the variables in the form. Rather write them somewhere so they are easy to change. If you ever made changes to the form and added a variable or changed a variable name, you don't have to change this particular code. This means that this function is usable on different forms. The idea is to write function that that can be re-used. Not those that are dedicated to one thing. OOP.

The getExpectedInput function would probably return an array. You can name this whatever you like or use any method.